# What is the total number of rectangles in a grid that do not include a circle?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am having trouble solving this question where I have to find the total number of rectangles in the grid shown below that do not include any of the circles.

I believe that this question can be done using the complement through
[total number of rectangles] - [total number of rectangles including 1 circle] - [total number including 2 circles]. However, I am stuck how to count the number of rectangles including 1 circle and the number of rectangles including 2 circles

[image: rectangular grid containing two circles]

Comment: Is there something you could not understand in my solution ? You have not shown any reaction yet

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish To clarify, are the number of choices due to the number of lines to each side of the circle? (i.e. For d1, 3C1 because there are 3 lines to the left of the circle, 5C1 because there are 5 lines to the right of the circle and so on?) not sure if i got the correct logic. Thanks.

Comment: yes. your logic is totally correct. It is also applied for upper and bottom lines

Answer (score 2):

Let the left dot called as $d_1$ and the right one is $d_2$. So,the answer is the number of all rectangles - the number of rectangles which contain $d_1$ or $d_2$.

- The number of rectangles that contain $d_1$: $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}=120$$
- The number of rectangles that contain $d_2$: $$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}=120$$
- The number of rectangles that contain both $d_1$ and $d_2$: $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}=36$$

So, $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{2}-(120+120-36)=216$$